# pyqt5 QPushButton() ( with clicked.connect() ) does not work

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I have this very simple GUI, but I can't get the pressbutton working. I have tried using *partial* and *lambda* in the clicked.connect command, but had no luck. I know that I could only ever press the button once, since I don't have a loop to keep changing the location of each new input box, but I just want to get it working first.

Thanks you for any advice

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QSizePolicy,
                         QDoubleSpinBox, QLabel, QCheckBox, QMainWindow,
QGridLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar



class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        # Geometry of main window:
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 1000)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simulation')

        #---------------------------------------
                # Button for adding blades
        blade_button = QPushButton('Add', self)
        blade_button.clicked.connect(self.add_Bladebox)
        blade_button.move(800, 600)


        #---------------------------------------

        self.show()

    # Method for input box:
    def inputBox(self, left, top, maxvalue, step, default,decimals):
        box = QDoubleSpinBox(self)
        box.move(left,top)
        box.setDecimals(decimals)
        box.setMaximum(maxvalue)
        box.setSingleStep(step)
        box.setProperty("value", default)
        box.resize(box.sizeHint())
        return box

    # Method for adding blade boxes
    def add_Bladebox(self):
        left = 900
        top = 500
        maxvalue = 3
        step=1
        default=0
        decimals=1
        blade_box = self.inputBox(left, top, maxvalue, step, default, decimals)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is PlotCanvas'? i have this error on your code: NameError: name 'PlotCanvas' is not defined

Comment: You have an apostrophe right after canvas. That's probably why it didn't work. Also, I'll remove the version of the command that does work and leave the one that does not (for clarity).

Comment: You can also just leave out the canvas altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QSizePolicy,
                         QDoubleSpinBox, QLabel, QCheckBox, QMainWindow,
QGridLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar



class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        # Geometry of main window:
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 1000)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simulation')

        #---------------------------------------
                # Button for adding blades
        blade_button = QPushButton('Add', self)
        blade_button.clicked.connect(self.add_Bladebox)
        blade_button.move(800, 600)


        #---------------------------------------

        self.show()

    # Method for input box:
    def inputBox(self, left, top, maxvalue, step, default,decimals):
        box = QDoubleSpinBox(self)
        box.move(left,top)
        box.setDecimals(decimals)
        box.setMaximum(maxvalue)
        box.setSingleStep(step)
        box.setProperty("value", default)
        box.resize(box.sizeHint())
        box.show()

    # Method for adding blade boxes
    def add_Bladebox(self):

        print('This is Ok')

        left = 900
        top = 500
        maxvalue = 3
        step = 1
        default = 0
        decimals = 1
        self.inputBox(left, top, maxvalue, step, default, decimals)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```